# I try to create AR app by using react native and deepAr

Tags: reactjs, react-native, augmented-reality

I'm trying AR for mobile apps by using deepAr in React Native, my app is working perfectly, ask all permissions but the camera is not open black screen shows, If anyone has an idea how to solve this issue so kindly help me

Comment: Please share some code